# Not able to read string interpolation in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, express, mean-stack, observable

I am subscribing to a service that is returning a working `User` object with properties (`firstName`, `lastName`, `email`, etc.)

I am not able to display the value in my view. If I write `{{ user }}` the browser displays `[object Object]`, but when I put `{{ user.firstName }}` I get errors saying undefined property.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { User } from "./user.model";
import { Message } from "../messages/message.model";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-profile', 
    template: `
    <h1>This is my profile page!</h1>
    <div>
      {{ user.firstName }}
    </div>

    `
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

    user: User;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.authService.getUser().subscribe(
        (user: User) => {
        console.log(user.firstName);    //returns firstName of user object in console
        this.user = user;
        }
      );
    }    
}
```

and from my authService

```
getUser()  {
      const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token') : '';
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/user/' + userId + token) 
      .map((response: Response) => {
      const user = response.json();
      let profileUser = new User(user.obj.email, user.obj.password, user.obj.firstName, user.obj.lastName);
      this.profileUser = profileUser;
      console.log(profileUser);
      return this.profileUser;
      })
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json())); 
    }
```

Comment: What if you try safe navigation: `{{ user?.firstName }}`? The user is loaded asynchronously, so when the component first loads there is no `user` and therefore no `firstName`. Alternatively, look into using the `AsyncPipe` and exposing the user as an observable in the component.

Comment: The safe navigation worked perfectly, I didn't even know this was an option or that  angular would have this problem when you subscribe to something. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your template is rendering faster than your service returns the data. Try this to solve the problem:

```
<h1>This is my profile page!</h1>
<div>
  {{ user?.firstName }}
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!! I have spent 5 hours at least trying to understand this. Is this a normal occurance? No tutorials say to put the question mark..is this something that should always be done?

Comment: see documentation here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have a few options to do it:

1. setting a trigger flag when data is ready
2. use safe navigation

   ```
   {{ user?.firstName }}
   ```
3. use [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html)

Comment: It might be helpful to show what each of these looks like. Note if you include a code block in a list entry it needs each line to start with 8 spaces, not 4.